# How to track pageviews in RemixJS?

Tags: remix.run

I am building a Remix app, and wanted to record some user analytics in my database based on what page the user was viewing. I also wanted to do so on a route by route basis, rather than just simply the raw URL.

For example: I wanted to know "user viewed URL /emails/123" as well as "user viewed route /emails/$emailId"

This problem could be generalized as "I want to run a piece of server code once per user navigation"

For my tracking I'm assuming users have javascript enabled in their browser.

## Solutions I tried:

### Record in the loader

This would be something like:

```
export const loader: LoaderFunction = async ({ request, params }): Promise<LoaderData> => {
  myDb.recordPageVisit(request.url);
}
```

This doesn't work because the loader can be called multiple times per page visit (eg. after an action is run)

It's possible that there's some value hidden in the request parameter that tells us whether this is an initial page load or if it's a later visit, but if so I couldn't find it, including when I examined the raw HTTP requests.

It's also annoying to have to put this code inside of every loader.

### Record the URL in the node code

I'm using @remix-run/node as my base remix server, so I have the escape hatch of setting up node middleware, and I thought that might be a good answer:

```
  const app = express();
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url.indexOf("_data") == -1) {
      myDb.recordPageVisit(req.url);
    }
    next();
  });
```

I tried ignoring routes with `_data` in them, but that didn't work because remix is being efficient and when the user navigates, it is using an ajax-y call to only get the loaderData rather than getting the full rendered page from the server. I know this is the behavior of Remix, but I had not remembered it before I went down this path :facepalm:

As far as I can tell it's impossible to stateless-ly track unique pageviews (ie based purely on the current URL) - you need see the user's previous page as well.

I wondered if referer would allow this to work statelessly, but it appears that the referer is not behaving how I'd hoped: the referer header is already set to the current page in the first loader request for the data for the page. So initial load and load-after-mutation appear identical based on referer. I don't know if this is technically a bug, but it's certainly not the behavior I'd expect.

Comment: To incorporate google analytics, I referenced the example on the repository: https://github.com/remix-run/remix/tree/main/examples/google-analytics

Comment: Another alternative is to use Fathom, a privacy-respecting Google Analytics alternative, which is EU-friendly, see usefathom.com — see how Kent Dodds website use `fathom-client` in `entry.client.tsx`: https://github.com/kentcdodds/kentcdodds.com/blob/main/app/entry.client.tsx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up solving this by doing the pageview tracking in the client. To support recording this in the DB, I implemented a route that just received the POSTs when the location changed.

The documentation for react-router's useLocation actually includes this exact scenario as an example.

From https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation:

```
function App() {
  let location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }, [location]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

However, that doesn't quite work in remix - the location value is changed after actions (same text value, but presumably different ref value). So I started saving the last location string seen, and then only report a new pageview when the location string value has changed.

So after adding that stateful tracking of the current location, I landed on:

```
export default function App() {
  // ...other setup omitted...
  const [lastLocation, setLastLocation] = useState("");
  let location = useLocation();
  const matches = useMatches();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastLocation == location.pathname) {
      return;
    }
    // there are multiple matches for parent route + root route, this 
    // will give us the leaf route
    const routeMatch = matches.find((m) => m.pathname == location.pathname);
    setLastLocation(location.pathname);
    fetch("/api/pageview", {
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
        url: location.pathname,
        // routeMatch.id looks like: "/routes/email/$emailId"
        route: routeMatch?.id }),
      method: "POST",
    }).then((res) => {
      if (res.status != 200) {
        console.error("could not report pageview:", res);
      }
    });
  }, [location]);
```

The matches code is not necessary for tracking just raw URLs, but I wanted to extract the route form (eg /emails/$emailId), and matches.id is a close match to that value - I strip "routes/" serverside. Matches docs: https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usematches

Client side pageview tracking is a bit annoying since clients are flaky, but for the current remix behavior I believe this is the only real option.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a nice way to handle this.

Answer (score -2):

Did it a different way for routes, remix is funny cuz of the whole parent route thing `*` so I use a route logger

Beans.io

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/beansio`

Comment: This sounds like it'd be similar to what I tried in "Record the URL in the node code", where I ran into trouble where I couldn't differentiate between the initial page load and later loads of the data after an action - does beans have a trick to differentiating those? I didn't see a source link to understand how it works.

Comment: Yes beans does have a way of differentiating routes it understands the way remix creates routes and has a feature that is able to understands it on the fly something like test/$Id.player.$food would log like /test/:id/player/:food

Comment: What I saw when looking at using a route based logger was that a single page visit would look like multiple visits to the same route, due to the fact that the loader gets invoked after actions. If a user visits a page and then completes an action on the page, will it log one event or multiple events?

Comment: I dont think this solution has that problem based on how the middleware is added, you can try it though here is the github repo you can look at it though.  https://github.com/virgincodes/beansio

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. This unfortunately doesn't seem to avoid the "logging multiple times when a user takes an action" problem. This question is about pageviews, and not actions. 

Ultimately what you're doing here is not meaningfully different from what I wrote in my "Record the URL in the node code" dismissed solution.

beansio seems like a nice way to add some metadata on your route logger/keep track of a given user session. I'd personally be a bit hesitant to recreate remix's route creation logic by reading the filesystem since that seems potentially fragile.

Comment: Yeah, it's the most logical way to do it because of the way remix.js creates routes, I don't think logs things twice but would log post request, but I would check that though maybe its a bug I didn't notice if I fix it would u use it though (would fix it regardless though) @StephenSisk

Comment: Probably not worth the switching cost for me at this point, and as I mentioned the route parsing seems fragile. I also looked at trying to log the way you're doing it right now and didn't see a way to distinguish the multiple requests (POST vs GET won't work, there are multiple GETs)

Comment: Hmm interesting would still look more into it and really appreciate the feedback, so the only issue about your current implementation would be distinguishing the multiple get request right? or is there any other issue with your current implementation?, also at what point do you think I can hit you up again to ask you to check it out again.